# How to create history fact table?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, fact-table, datahistory

I have some entities in my Data Warehouse:

1. **Person** - with attributes personId, dateFrom, dateTo, and others those can be changed, e.g. last name, birth date and so on - slowly changing dimension
2. **Document** - documentId, number, type
3. **Address** - addressId, city, street, house, flat

The relations between (Person and Document) is One-To-Many  and  (Person and Address) is Many-To-Many.

My target is to create history fact table that can answer us following questions:

1. What persons with what documents lived at defined address on defined date?

2, What history of residents does defined address have on defined interval of time?

This is not only for what DW is designed, but I think it is the hardest thing in DW's design.

For example, Miss Brown with personId=1, documents with documentId=1 and documentId=2 had been lived at address with addressId=1 since 01/01/2005 to 02/02/2010 and then moved to addressId=2 where has been lived since 02/03/2010 to current date (NULL?). But she had changed last name to Mrs Green since 04/05/2006 and her first document with documentId=1 to documentId=3 since 06/07/2007. Mr Black with personId=2, documentId=4 has been lived at addressId=1 since 02/03/2010 to current date.

The expected result on our query for question 2 where addressId=1, and time interval is since 01/01/2000 to now, must be like:

Rows:

```
last_name="Brown", documentId=1, dateFrom=01/01/2005, dateTo=04/04/2006

last_name="Brown", documentId=2, dateFrom=01/01/2005, dateTo=04/04/2006

last_name="Green", documentId=1, dateFrom=04/05/2006, dateTo=06/06/2007

last_name="Green", documentId=2, dateFrom=04/05/2006, dateTo=06/06/2007

last_name="Green", documentId=2, dateFrom=06/07/2007, dateTo=02/01/2010

last_name="Green", documentId=3, dateFrom=06/07/2007, dateTo=02/01/2010

last_name="Black", documentId=4, dateFrom=02/03/2010, dateTo=NULL
```

I had an idea to create fact table with composite key (personId, documentId, addressId, dateFrom) but I have no idea how to load this table and then get that expected result with this structure.

**I will be pleased for any help!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question @Argnist!

So to create some common language for my example, you want a

- DimPerson (PK=kcPerson, suggorate key for unique Persons=kPerson, type 2 dim)
- DimDocument (PK=kcDocument, suggorate key for unique Documents=kDocument, type 2 dim)
- DimAddress (PK=kcAddress, suggorate key for unique Addresses=kAddress, type 2 dim)

A colleague has written a short blog on the usage of two surrogate keys to explain the above dims '[Using Two Surrogate Keys on Dimensions](http://www.consolidata.co.uk/SQL-blog/2008/07/using-2-surrogate-keys-on-dime.html)'.

I would always add 
DimDate with PK in the form yyyymmdd
to any data warehouse with extra attribute columns.

Then you would have your fact table as

- FactHistory (FKs=kcPerson, kPerson, kcDocument, kDocument, kcPerson, kPerson, kDate)
  plus any aditional measures.

Then joining on the "kc"s you can show the current Person/Document/Address dimension information.
If you joined on the "k"s you can show the historic Person/Document/Address dimension information.

The downside of this is that this fact table needs one row for each person/document/address/date combination. But it really is a very narrow table, since the table just has a number of foreign keys.

The advantage of this is it is very easy to query for the sorts of questions you were asking.

Alternatively, you could have your fact table as

- FactHistory (FKs=kcPerson, kPerson, kcDocument, kDocument, kcPerson, kPerson, kDateFrom, kDateTo)
  plus any aditional measures.

This is obviously much more compact, but the querying becomes more complex. You could also put a view over the Fact table to make it easier to query!

The choice of solution depends on the frequency of change of the data. I suspect that it will not be changing that quickly, so teh alternate design of the fact table may be better.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Marcus D Thank you. I thought similar but without "k"s keys in fact table (Did I understand your names right? kcPerson - surrogate key for indentifying a row, and kPerson - natural key for identifying one person?).

Comment: But FactHistory (FKs=kcPerson, kPerson, kcDocument, kDocument, kcAddress, kAddress, kDateFrom, kDateTo) yields that we have to update old facts' kDateTo - this is not good I thought. May be better to have one kDateFrom... And one question more. Type 2 scd in DimDocument or DimAddress - for set of documents/addresses of one Person or what?

Comment: @Argnist. we would use two integer surrogate keys kcPerson and kPerson. kperson would be a surrogate key that points to the unique individual (regardless of name changes/gender changes etc), kcperson would be a surrogate key that points to the specific instance of that person (their specific name/gender etc). Have a check of the link I included. We dont keep natural keys on fact tables. always surrogate keys - much faster, also gets around the problem when your business users wants to change the natural key name, but retain a link to the history (yes we have had it happen!!)

Comment: @Argnist. regarding your second comment ... The issue on updating records on the fact table is irritating, but I cant see a way around it. With either of my Fact table models.

Comment: @Argnist. regarding the question in your second comment ... It may not make sense to have type 2 for all dims, but from your example it looked like your Documents could "change" so you would want to store the changes in type 2 dim (maybe version numbers of the doc?), similarly for changes in your Person info. Obviously if my understanding was incorrect, then make individual dims (or specific columns on dims type 1)

Comment: @Marcus D Thank you, it's exactly what I need!

Comment: @Marcus D. I've been confronted with difficulties of loading fact table, you suggested. What if we had new rows which have already loaded or the date of the fact is between existing dates. And adding of new document, for example, when person has several addresses, yields new several fact rows for each address.

Comment: I guess this depends on the need you have in your DWH from a reporting perspective, you could do what you suggest, or just add the new fact records for the most recent Person/Address combination. Both are reasonable, but if you want to do "as at" reporting, then if you add a new document you may not want to add the historic Person/Address records since that document never existed at that Person/Address combination ... just thinking out loud and again it depends on your application/report requirements. If you want some more detail, I could add another "Answer" ...